# How to insert a PIL.Image in a PyQt canvas - PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, python-imaging-library

I want to show some data in a gauge in my application. I am using pyqt5.

I am creating a `canvas` in which my plots or my gauge is going to be displayed(some time a plot another time a gauge):

```
class MplCanvas(FigureCanvasQTAgg):
     def __init__(self, parent=None, width=8, height=6, dpi=100):
         fig = Figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi)
         self.axes = fig.add_subplot(111)
         super(MplCanvas, self).__init__(fig)
```

and adding this `canvas` in my main layout:

```
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.canvas = MplCanvas(self, width=12, height=8, dpi=100)

        self.layout_plot.addWidget(self.canvas)
        self.show()
```

I found a link on [how to create a gauge](https://www.andrewshay.me/blog/how-to-create-a-gauge-speedometer-graphic-with-python/):

```
import PIL
from PIL import Image

percent = 20  # Percent for gauge
output_file_name = 'new_gauge.png'


percent = percent / 100
rotation = 180 * percent  # 180 degrees because the gauge is half a circle
rotation = 90 - rotation  # Factor in the needle graphic pointing to 50 (90 degrees)

dial = Image.open('needle.png')
dial = dial.rotate(rotation, resample=PIL.Image.BICUBIC, center=loc)  # Rotate needle

gauge = Image.open('gauge.png')
gauge.paste(dial, mask=dial)  # Paste needle onto gauge
gauge.save(output_file_name)
```

I try to add the `gauge` to my `canvas in this way:

```
dial = Image.open('needle.png')
dial = dial.rotate(rotation, resample=PIL.Image.BICUBIC, center=loc)  # Rotate needle

gauge = Image.open('gauge.png')
gauge.paste(dial, mask=dial)  # Paste needle onto gauge
self.layout_plot.removeWidget(self.canvas)
self.layout_plot.addWidget(gauge)
self.canvas.draw()
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: addWidget(self, QWidget, stretch: int = 0, alignment: Union[Qt.Alignment, Qt.AlignmentFlag] = Qt.Alignment()): argument 1 has unexpected type 'PngImageFile'
```

how to add this `gauge` in my `canvas`?

Comment: I haven't seen any examples of drawing your own gauge using Matplotlib. You might consider using a [QGraphicsView](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsview.html) as a canvas and drawing [QGraphicsItems](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#details)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is confusing since if what you indicate is analyzed it can be interpreted as:

- How to add the PIL.image in a layout to which the canvas was also added. If so, then the problem is that the addWidget method expects a QWidget so you have to use a QWidget like QLabel to put the image there, and then put the QLabel in the layout:

  ```
  from PIL.ImageQt import ImageQt
  ```

  ```
  im = ImageQt(gauge).copy()
  pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(im)
  label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
  label.setPixmap(pixmap)
  self.layout_plot.addWidget(label)
  ```
- How to add the PIL.Image inside the canvas, and in that case you should not use the layout but the imshow method:

  ```
  self.canvas.axes.imshow(np.asarray(gauge))
  ```